# Why is class_eval sometimes used when re-opening the class could work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, class-eval

I've come across some code in a Rails app in the form of

```
ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo.class_eval do
  def bar?
    @bar_field == 'true'
  end
end
```

and I'm wondering why they didn't just do

```
class ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo
  def bar?
    @bar_field == 'true'
  end
end
```

Are there any advantages in using `class_eval` when there isn't anything you want to pass in to the new code?

Comment: Is the rails app you mentioned open source? If so, can you post the link?

Comment: Also, what's the library being monkey-patched? What's the patch?

Comment: @tompave sorry, it isn't open source.

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure, but one thing is that with class_eval, you are sure that the class will already be loaded before the code is evaluated. If you just open the class definition, even if the class is not yet loaded, it will be created.  In the second case, if the same methods are then defined, your code will be overwritten.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm ok, no problem. What about the third party library? And the code being added?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo do
  def original?
    true
  end
end

ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo.class_eval do
  def baz?
    true
  end
end

ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo.original? #=> true
ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo.baz? #=> true

class ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo
  def bar?
    true
  end
end

ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo.original? #=> undefined method
ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo.baz? #=> undefined method
ThirdPartyLibrary::Foo.bar? #=> true
```

class_eval 'adds' something to an existing class and your second example just defines the class new and overwrites everything that was there before.
This is used for example when you want to monkeypatch or extend libraries.